# Disable built in GCP VPC-Firewall

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall, google-cloud-networking

I am having a Firebase project which is accessable via firebase webapp. This app need some information from a backend. So there is a VPC network with an external ip.

Now there are these bulid in icmp and rdp rules. Icmp and rdp must not be externally accessible. So I disabled the rules and created new deny rules with higher priority e.g.prio 1 , but pinging to the external address is still possible.

I assume that if I adjust the rules as above, that a ping no longer works.

Is this correct?

Here is a screenshot from my rules
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of your current rules? I think you meant to add it with the "(1)"

Comment: Screenshot added @pa

Comment: I see that you have a firewall rule denying ICMP. Can you confirm if you’re still able to ping the external IP address? Also, can you review if the firewall rule is being applied to the correct VPC network?